# KeyError: 'Unable to find stateless DjangoApp called app'

Tags: python, django

Why the DjangoApp app can't be found?

### Given result

After executing `manage.py runserver` in the console Django is starting properly but in case I'm calling http://127.0.0.1:8000/dash_simple/app1/ a KeyError was thrown:
Django Version:     3.1.3
Exception Type:     KeyError
Exception Value:

'Unable to find stateless DjangoApp called app'

### Expected result

After executing `manage.py runserver` in the console Django is starting properly and the related page is shown for http://127.0.0.1:8000/dash_simple/app1/

#### dash_test/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('dash_simple/', include ('dash_simple.urls')),                        
]
```

#### dash_test/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'dash_simple.apps.DashSimpleConfig',
]
```

#### dash_test/dash_simple/apps.py

```
class DashSimpleConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'dash_simple'
```

#### dash_simple/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('app1/', views.app, name='app')
]
```

#### dash_simple/views.py

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, template_name='dash_simple/home.html')


def app(request):
    return render(request, template_name='dash_simple/app1.html')
```

#### dash_simple/templates/dash_simple/app1.html

```
{% load plotly_dash %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>App 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <H1>I'm App 1</H1>
    <p>
        {% plotly_app name="app" %}
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your URL should just be http://127.0.0.1/app1. You don’t need to include the template name

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work, because the Django Project has an include for integrated apps and expects dash_simple/ to be part of the context. I've just corrected my question. Soory - was my fault.

Comment: Register Your app on setting.py file      **dash_simple/urls.py** => `urlpatterns = [path('app1/', views.app, name='app'),path('', views.home, name='home')
]`

Comment: I've changed the  order of given urlpatterns (position 1: path('app1/', position 2: path('/'). Result:  KeyError Exception Value:

'Unable to find stateless DjangoApp called app' @Domadiya: No effect.

Answer (score 8):

Faced similar issue. 
 
 In `dash_simple/urls.py` you need to import your dash application i.e.:

`from dash_simple import your_dash_script_file_name`

As simple as that!

Answer (score 1):

For future reference. In my case getting 'Unable to find stateless DjangoApp called "AppName"'. For one of my plotly app it worked and for the other one i did not. I started verifying what one off them had and the other not.

After some hours i noticed this set of imports i made few days ago on the /views of the app that was serving the html template that showed the plot, while setting the first.

`from plotly.offline import plot`
`import plotly.graph_objs as go`
`from .plot import *`

I copied this to the other app that rendered had the view of the second plot. but the compilation failed because the 3rd import was not being found. Because of this i went into the reference of the import in the first plot and it was the module that had all the code of the first plot, so i changed the last import on the views of the django app that rendered my second plot

Basically. My solution was to also do the three imports on the views of the django app that is rendering the html that contains the plot and change the last line to import the script/module of the dash plotly app that i'm looking to render.